# Business friendly language name for "sucking-up"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a business friendly language name to describe the action of a person sucking-up (teacher's pet, leech, give your pinky they grab your whole arm person, someone who tries to use another person for their own gain without giving back)

e.g.

> John warned Tony that if he went to lunch with his coworker Pete thinking he will gain a friend, Pete will end up acting like a suck-up.

A good word description is *acting like a sycophant* which has the meaning I am looking for:

> Definition: A person who acts obsequiously towards someone important in order to gain advantage.

However to say someone is  *acting like a sycophant* in writing in an e-mail or verbally sounds like a strong insult.

I am looking for the  formal word for *sucking up*?

Comment: The implication will still be _insulting_ whatever term you use. How can it then be a _business friendly_ term? (am not the downvoter, BTW)

Comment: The phrase *"brown noser"*, while still not formal, might work in this context.

Comment: I've never understood how *brown noser* isn't considered incredibly vulgar, but I agree with @BradC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid sounding insulting would be to circumvent the use of a noun to label the person, using the verb 'ingratiate' instead:

John warned Tony that if he went to lunch with his coworker Pete thinking he will gain a friend, he would eventually realise Pete's only interest was in ingratiating himself.

Ingratiate: "Bring oneself into favour with someone by flattering or trying to please them."

‘a sycophantic attempt to ingratiate herself with the local aristocracy’

[Oxford Dictionary definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ingratiate)

Comment: Agree. Maybe if one uses a noun it sounds insulting for business use as one is labeling the person and not their behavior so ingratiate is a good answer

Comment: It might be worth adding that you could also use the synonym "to curry favor", which arguably sounds a little milder: "John warned Tony that if he went to lunch with his coworker Pete thinking he will gain a friend, he would eventually realise Pete's only interest was to curry favor." The Oxford Dictionary defines this as follows: "Ingratiate oneself with someone through obsequious behaviour."
‘a wimpish attempt to curry favour with the new bosses’ https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/curry_favour

Comment: thanks yes I can use both. So the best answer for business sense it to use  ingratiate or try curry favour.

Answer (score 1):

Call him/her a **fawner**.

It qualifies as an euphemism for *sycophant*.

---

fawner:

> a person who gives a servile display of exaggerated flattery or affection

Comment: Still an insult

Comment: I interpret fawner more like admirer which is not really the same as suck-up

Answer (score 0):

You could use the word parasite, but 'Pete' would need to not be present for the conversation.

Parasite:
derogatory
a person who habitually relies on or exploits others and gives nothing in return.

Comment: Thank you for your interest and welcome to ELU. Please take the site [tour] so that you can compose your answers as per the requirements of this site. (Incomplete answers may be deleted).

Comment: unfortunately it is offensive in a business sense

Answer (score 0):

How about'prig'? Google defines a prig as"a self-righteously moralistic person who behaves as if they are superior to others".